# Print variable value from automake file

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to debug a problem with a build system which uses Automake.  Some of the files are not being compiled, which I suspect is a problem with one of the variables being incorrect.  Is there something I can put in the `Makefile.am` to cause it to print out the value of the variable:

E.g.

```
foo = some_file.c another_file.c

print_out_something_helpful($(foo))
```

How would I integrate the `print_out_something_helpful` function with the rules?

Sample output desired would be something like:

```
 >> Files to compile are "some_file.c another_file.c"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `echo $(foo)` to print the variable value,

```
foo = some_file.c another_file.c

all:
     echo $(foo))
```

Comment: This does print out the value, but is also reporting `/bin/bash: some_file.c: Permission denied.`  Looks like it's trying to execute the file as a command.

Comment: Ooooops!!! Sorry for misguiding you I was thinking something else inmind. Check the answer again.